# Showing that $ \oint _C xdy-ydx=x_1y_2-x_2y_1$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $C$ be the interval from point $(x_1,x_2)$ to point $(x_2,y_2)$

> Show that $\displaystyle \oint _C xdy-ydx=x_1y_2-x_2y_1$

**My attempt:**

Acording Green's theoram
$\displaystyle \oint _C xdy-ydx=\displaystyle \iint \bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}-\frac{-\partial y}{\partial x} \bigg)dxdy =\color{red}0$

Why I got zero? how can I solve this? any hints?

Comment: is $c$ is circle or line ?

Comment: @d_e $c$ is a line

Comment: OK. so as far as I know you are not allow to use Green.

Comment: Green's theorem can only be used for closed curves.

Comment: You have to state precisely what the path is. The function to be integrated is not the gradient of a potential so the expected answer can only be reached if a specific path is given. You can't use Green's theorem for not-closed line integral.

Comment: Suppose you should avoid the use of closed line integral sign $\oint$ for non-closed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use this parameterization of the line segment from point $(x_1,y_1)$ to point $(x_2,y_2)$:

$$x=x_1+(x_2-x_1)t$$
$$y=y_1+(y_2-y_1)t$$
$$0\le t\le 1$$

Then $dx=(x_2-x_1)dt,\ dy=(y_2-y_1)dt$, and calculating the integral is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for the integral
$$
\int_Cxdy-ydx,
$$
write it as two separate integrals.

For
$$
\int_Cxdy,
$$
write $x$ as a function of $y$ (find the equation of the line and solve for $x$).  Then use the definition of a line integral to evaluate.

The other integral is similar.

Comment: A problem with that approach is that $y$ is not a function of $x$ if the line segment is vertical and $x$ is not a function of $y$ if the line segment is horizontal.

Comment: @RoryDaulton In those cases, $x$ or $y$ isn't changing, so $dx$ or $dy$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @Rory Daulton I think I solved it:

> $$\oint_C-ydx+xdy$$

$$\int\limits _{t=0}^{t=1}=-(y_1+t(y_2-y_1))(x_2-x_1)dt+\int\limits _{t=0}^{t=1}=(x_1+t(x_2-x_1))(y_2-y_1)dt$$

$$=-y_1(x_2-x_1)-\frac{(y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)}{2}+\frac{(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)}{2}$$
$$=-y_1(x_2-x_1)+x_1(y_2-y_1)=\color{red}{\boxed{x_1y_2-x_2y_1}}$$